# Nextjs - Reactjs - Links patterns - Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working with NextJS. I'm working on a layout. Inside my layout there is some nav component with links inside. When I try to create my links with anchor inside, my console returns me :

> Nextjs - Reactjs - Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected
>   to receive a single React element child

Howerver it is just the classic pattern for NextJS, here an example of what my links look like :

```
<Link href={{pathname:'/blog'}} className={style.links_items}
to="/blog"> <a title="Blog">BLOG -</a></Link>
```

It's work only if I do that :

```
 <Link href={{pathname:'/blog'}} className={style.links_items}
    to="/blog"> BLOG -</Link>
```

But then, I got a warning :

> You're using a string directly inside `<Link>`. This usage has been
>   deprecated. Please add an `<a>` tag as child of `<Link>`

If someone have any hint, would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a space before the `a` element in the link. That means the link has two child nodes: A text node (with the space in it), and the `a` element. Remove the space:

```
<Link href={{pathname:'/blog'}} className={style.links_items}
to="/blog"><a title="Blog">BLOG -</a></Link>
```

Comment: How to avoid hours of Googling, thanks for this useful information

Comment: @Webman - With luck, when this comes up for someone else, they'll find your question and this answer with a search. :-)

Comment: I found this in a search. Removing the space made it work. I don't like how we can't use a space. Why does this happen?

Comment: @jackblank - Because with the space there, you're specifying two children: A text node, and an `a` element. That's a position in which whitespace is significant.